# Command not found after installing gem

Tags: shell, middleman

After a version conflict I re-installed the middleman gem. It seems to have deleted the path as well which leads to the error

```
command not found: middleman
```

I am however not certain how to relink the command to the gem! Has anyone experienced a similar issue before and know what the best solution is to relink the two together?

Below my gem env

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.4.3 (2017-12-14 patchlevel 205) [x86_64-darwin17]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/pimzonneveld/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/pimzonneveld/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/pimzonneveld/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/pimzonneveld/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/pimzonneveld/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/pimzonneveld/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-17
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/pimzonneveld/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
     - /Users/pimzonneveld/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://gems.rubyforge.org/", "http://gems.github.com"]
     - :benchmark => false
     - "gem" => "--no-document"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
     - http://gems.github.com
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/pimzonneveld/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.1/libexec
     - ./bin
     - ./node_modules/.bin
     - /Users/pimzonneveld/.rbenv/shims
     - /Users/pimzonneveld/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/sbin
```

Installed middleman gems

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

font-awesome-middleman (4.5.0)
jquery-middleman (3.1.2)
middleman (4.2.1)
middleman-autoprefixer (2.9.0)
middleman-blog (4.0.2)
middleman-cli (4.2.1)
middleman-core (4.2.1)
middleman-sprockets (4.1.1)
```